# is there a way to "suspend" the counter of the enumitem package?

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I'm trying to set up a particular enumerated list, where I need to keep the counter in between `\begin{enumerate}` environments. Something like the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.85cm, label=A\arabic*.]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}

write some other text here

% write another enumerated list here of the same type, but continuing with the numbering of the previous one.
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.85cm, label=A\arabic*.]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
```

So clearly this doesn't work because the second enumerated list starts from the beginning. I tried using the `suspend` and `resume` commands within the `mdwlist` package but this didn't work.

Comment: When you use label directly as an optional argument, you need to use resume* not just resume. See the manual

Comment: I tried with `\resume*{enumerate}` but it gives me an error. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @aaragon You can't mix commands from `enumitem` and `mdwlist`

Comment: See Christians answer. Plus it does not hurt to look in the enumitem manual

Comment: @daleif I did look at the manual of course, and even did a quick search on counter to see if I found something. But well, I guess I overlooked the `resume*` option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need to deal with the underlying counters directly if you are using `enumitem`. You can just use `resume`, `resume*` and/or `series`, with or without customised lists, depending on just how elaborate your needs are.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}   

\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.85cm, label=A\arabic*.]
    \item First item
    \item Second item
  \end{enumerate}
  If you don't mind having to re-specify everything:
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.85cm, label=A\arabic*., resume]
    \item Third item
    \item Fourth item
  \end{enumerate}
  If you would prefer not to re-specify:
  \begin{enumerate}[resume*]
    \item Fifth item
    \item Sixth item
  \end{enumerate}
  What if you want to use first one enumeration:
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.85cm, label=D\arabic*., series=denum]
    \item First item
    \item Second item
  \end{enumerate}
  And then another:
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.85cm, label=(\alph*)., series=alphenum]
    \item First item
    \item Second item
  \end{enumerate}
  And then you want to continue the first?
  \begin{enumerate}[resume*=denum]
    \item Third item
    \item Fourth item
  \end{enumerate}
  Perhaps you even want to continue the second:
  \begin{enumerate}[resume*=alphenum]
    \item Third item
    \item Fourth item
  \end{enumerate}
  Too much work?
  \newlist{blist}{enumerate}{1}
  \setlist[blist]{leftmargin=0.85cm, label=B\arabic*.}
  \begin{blist}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
  \end{blist}
  And then you can have something entirely different:
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=.3\textwidth, label=\Roman*)]
    \item First Roman
    \item Second Roman
  \end{enumerate}
  Before continuing:
  \begin{blist}[resume]
    \item Third item
    \item Fourth item
  \end{blist}

\end{document}
```

[image: many lists]